# Работа с каталогами и файлами по символьной ссылке в PHP

Tags: php, debian

Имеется скрипт написанный на PHP 5.6
Имеется примонтированный к серверу на базе Debian 8 дополнительный диск, на котором лежат фотографии и xml файлы.
В связи с тем что данных много (15гб) и они нужны только на чтение, не хотелось бы их хранить в том же каталоге что и сам сайт.
В итоге я создал символьные ссылки на два каталога где лежат по папкам эти данные.
Если взять например редактор nano то он прекрасно справляется с редактированием файла в этом каталоге по новому пути. Но file_exists в скрипте говорит что нет такого файла... и соответственно файл не читается и не отдается скриптом.

Можно ли как то решить вопрос?

```
ls -l /var/www/prof/data/www/xxx.ru/Index1
root prof 17 Apr 20 11:53 /var/www/prof/data/www/xxx.ru/Index1 -> /mnt/disk2/Index1
```

Comment: вывод в вопрос `ls -l symlink` символьной ссылки добавьте в вопрос, приведите код где делаетсья `file_exists`, и dump переменной с путём до файла

Comment: @Naumov путь до файла верный, проверял.

Comment: `FollowSymlinks` в апаче включен?

Comment: а сервер от какого пользователя и группы  работает?

Comment: @Naumov у каждого домена свой пользователь, в данном случае prof

Comment: @teran Options +FollowSymLinks в htaccess прописано но не помогает

Comment: Вы от этого пользователя выполняете `ls -l`

Comment: *Options +FollowSymLinks в htaccess прописано но не помогает* — 1. файлы `.htaccess` принимает к сведению только программа *apache*. 2. в настройках вирт. хоста для этого должно быть включено явное разрешение (ключевое слово: allowoverride).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну как бы вообще то я точно знаю что `.htaccess` работает. Потому что там сотни правил написанных мной лично.

Answer (score 2):

Всегда читайте сперва на сайте http://php.net/ и до конца (+ комментарии ),
[до 90  % ответов лежат там](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php)

> К сожалению, **file_exists** не может связаться с удаленными серверами,
>   поэтому я использовал функцию fopen.

```
<?php
function fileExists($path){
    return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
}
?>
```

**file_exists**: Проверка происходит с помощью реальных UID/GID, а не эффективных идентификаторов.чтоб проверять через нее надо в path передавать реальный path а не symlink.

> **Примечание**. Результаты этой функции кэшируются. Смотрите
>   `clearstatcache ()` для получения более подробной информации.
>
> Это довольно большая нота. Не забывайте об этом, так как это может
>   заставить ваш `file_exists ()` вести себя непредсказуемо - возможно,
>   во время `production time`;)

Удачи !

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле дело не в `file_exists()` а в `open_basedir`
Помогло редактирование `VirtualHost`

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/prof/data:.:/var/www/prof/data/www/domen.ru/Index1/
```